# Rails 4.0.2 select & uniq

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using this activerecord query

```
CampaignType.includes(:campaign_description)
       .select('DISTINCT campaign_description_id, campaign_description.name')
       .where(:campaign_id => campaign_id)
```

which used to work on rails 3. Now it just gives a lot of DEPECATION warnings and an example:

```
Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string:

Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)
```

I've tried some different ways but I'm not getting there. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the `.references(:campaign_description`) line that the error message suggested?

Comment: I did. Just gives me another error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "campaign_description"`

Comment: The latest error happened actually because I was missing an 's' on campaign_description making it `campaign_descriptions.name`. This means adding the `references(:campaign_description)` and getting the DISTINCT out for a `.uniq` resolved ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why you got the error you mentioned in the comments, as I have done the same on my end and it works properly. However, there is actually another issue which may have the effect of solving your problem anyways.

Unfortunately, while it is technically allowed, if you use both an `includes` for eager loading in combination with a `select`, the `select` is effectively ignored (columns are not limited, you get a dump of everything). If eager loading is a significant requirement in this situation, you should be able to use the [`preload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload) method instead of `includes`. So your query would look something more like this:

```
campaign_type = CampaignType.preload(:campaign_description)
                .select("id, campaign_description_id, campaign_description.name")
                .joins(:campaign_description)
                .where(:campaign_id => campaign_id)
                .uniq
```

This will have the effect of eager loading the associated `campaign_description` model, while still selecting only the columns you specified. So long as your `CampaignType` model allows for accessing non-column attributes, you should have no trouble doing things like `campaign_type.name`. Note the `uniq` at the end adds the `DISTINCT` modifier to the select clause.

Regarding the `joins` method: Unfortunately, you still need to include this method, otherwise Rails will not implicitly perform an INNER JOIN, and thus any reference to `campaign_description` in the query will result in an error.

Also note that I've included the `id` field in the `select`. This is important, as it is required in order to load and access the associated `campaign_description` rows. If you did not include it, you would receive an empty collection if you tried `campaign_type.campaign_description` (as an example).

However, in your case, if you only want to return a model with only those `DISTINCT` fields and won't need to call the associated objects, you might not need the eager loading at all, and can safely ditch the `preload` and `id` part. Everything else would remain the same.

Comment: This suggested solution worked although the  `.references(:campaign_description)` works as well after messing things around a bit. Thanks